# how can I search for file within a directory (and sub's)

Tags: unix, bash

using bash shell, how can I search for a particular file in a folder (and its sub-folders)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
find dirname -name "filename"
```

For example:

```
find /usr/bin -name "*sh"
```

would find all the files that end in "sh" in that directory.

Or:

```
find /usr/share/doc -iname "*readme*"
```

would find all files with "readme" in their names regardless of capitalization in that directory and its subdirectories.

Comment: thanks, what about paging the results?

Comment: just add "| less" to the end of your find command

Comment: Are there any systems without `less` any more? If so, then `| more` will do an OK job. Or for really old systems: `| pg` - I had almost forgotten about that one.

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways to do this.

If slocate is installed and the database is up to date you can use "locate pattern | grep /path/you/wish/tosearch"

This is faster than the find command if you're searching a large directory or directories.

The other more traditional method is using the find command as Dennis has already pointed out so I won't go into that one.

Comment: The locate database is not updated frequently enough to use it for this purpose, most of the time.

Comment: That all depends on your data.  And how often updatedb runs.  Works fine on most systems as long as the file you're looking for is more than a day old.  In which case you'll need to use find.